# Compiler doesn't find .java classes inside source folder

Tags: eclipse, scala, compilation

I've recently created a new workspace in which I pasted my Scala project.
Some problems with the Scala syntax rised (problems that didn't show up before, who knows why) but the nastiest one is that the compiler no longer finds the .java classes inside the project!
That means, the are not compiled since I can't find them inside /bin.
Sometimes I get compile errors such as "X is not member of package Y", while other times, usually after I run "clean Project", the errors go away but I get a
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
exception at runtime, when one of those classes is called!
Why is this happening?

Comment: Which build tool are you using? SBT? Gradle? Maven?

Comment: Most people that work in Scala, like me, are using SBT.  With no configuration it can compile code, if standard layout is used.  It would be useful to dump the Gradle config.

Answer (score 0):

The main build tools (SBT, Gradle and Maven), expect by default source code in these locations:

- `src/main/java` for Java source code
- `src/main/scala` for Scala source code
- `src/test/java` for Java test source code
- `src/test/scala` for Scala test source code

Are you following this convention?

In addition, do package and folder structure match?

Comment: I am, all my code was previously in src/main/scala, then I moved my java classes to src/main/java but that didn't help. And yes, they do match but the java classes don't get compiled (can't see them inside /bin)